# Handling None as position in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

The built in pygame function: `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` returns the X and Y coordinates in a tuple when I am moving the mouse, but if I stop moving the mouse, the function returns `None`.

But, I want the computer to keep returning the current coordinates over and over again.

How do I do that?

What I am trying to do is write a function that makes it easier to get the mouse coordinates.

I want to be able to do following:

```
Xpos, Ypos = mouse_pos()
```

What I have right now is:

```
def mouse_pos():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if pos != None:
        x=a[0]
        y=a[1]

        return x, y

    else:
#here I want code that says: if pos is NoneType, x=(latest x-value) and y=(latest y-value)
```

So, how can i get pygame to not return None (and return current coordinates) even if mouse is stationary?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are using the API wrong, the fact that there are events doesn't mean any of them is a mouse event, and `pygame` fills the mouse position on mouse events.

The function `get_pos` shouldn't be calle to find out where the mouse is but rather to update your knowledge when it is changed.

The correct way to keep track of mouse position will be to have the following in you main game loop:

```
mouse_position = (0, 0) # initial value

while game_is_running: # your main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

Comment: _The function get_pos shouldn't be calle to find out where the mouse_: finding out where the mouse is is the sole purpose of `get_pos`

Comment: How can I put your given code inside a function? The way I did it was to copy and paste the last 3 lines of your code and put it in my function. In the end, return mouse_position. That does not work, I still get None, when mouse is stationary.

Comment: You shouldn't put this in a function whose whole purpose is to get the cursor position, `pygame.event.get` consumes the event queue meaning subsequent calls will not work. (And you would miss many important events)

Answer (score 2):

Remove your function. Just use `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`.

It's not `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` that returns `None`, it's your own function.

It will only set `pos` if there's an event in the event queue. If not, pos will be `None`.

But even worse is that every time you call your `mouse_pos` function, the event queue will be cleared. That will lead to events getting lost.

Comment: What do you mean by event queue? And, when you say remove your function, do you mean the mouse_pos function? In that case, does it mean that I cannot put the code to get mouse position inside a function?

Comment: @FrontEnd-Python What he meant by removing the `mouse_pos()` method is that it's *unnecessary* to write a separate method to get mouse position when there's already one built-in, the `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` function (which never returns `None` so your error would technically be nullified if you refactor your code this way). If you put it in the main update loop, it will perform the intended task — getting the mouse position over and over again, once on each loop iteration. The event queue is just a bunch of `pygame.event.Event` objects retrieved on a `pygame.event.get()` call.

Comment: @FrontEnd-Python When you create a window, it doesn't live on its own. It has to interact with your operation system/window manager. So when you move your mouse, press a key, try to close the window, or the windows needs to be repainted, the operation system/window manager sends a message to your window. This message will end up in a queue. In pygame, you can access this queue (in an abstracted form) with e.g. `pygame.event.get()`. In your case, if there's no event in this queue, `pos` will never be assigned.

Comment: @FrontEnd-Python Yes, just remove the `mouse_pos` function. It's actually harmful. Just do something like `x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()` in your loop.

Comment: 1) That gives me the cursor position in the beginning and it does not change as move the cursor.

Comment: @FrontEnd-Python It gives you the current mouse position every time you call it and it changed if you moved the mouse in the meantime